# I went to start my car and nothing happened and no sound

Tags: starting, vauxhall, astra

Vauxhall Astra 2000 model ,,,,
So I went to start the car everything came on but no sound or clicking, left it for husband​ to try and it clicked then turned over, went to Walsall was revering and it cut out so tried to restart it and nothing again. I've had the alternator checked and it's fine: kicking out 13.6 volts so no idea what it could be.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Could be a few things.. If you or a friend can do the basic testing. Try the following...

Firstly.. Check your battery terminals are making good contact with the battery, and that they are tightened up securely.

Also check the connections on the back of the starter motor are secure.. Whilst you're there check the starter motors mounting bolts are tight too.

Check the engine earth strap connection is clean and tight.

Next time it won't turn over.. Try giving the starter motor a few light taps with a hammer. DON'T have  anyone try and start it while you're under the bonnet!!

If after giving it a few taps it then turns over, you've likely got a faulty starter motor which will require replacing.

If the problem still exists you may have a wiring issue etc which will require more in depth investigation.

Answer (score 1):

I would check the Spark Plugs first to see if they give out spark, next I would check if gasoline is going to the engine by checking the gas tubes that connect to it. If no gas is going could be the fuel pump. Are you getting any sound when you start it, does it sound like its trying to give ignition?.